# why the template argument deduction/substitution failed in the code?-

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I am using compiler g++ 6.3.0 (c++14).
In the code-

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int f(auto a){return a;}

int f1(auto (*g)(int),int a) {return g(a);}

main()
{
    std::cout<< f1(f,8);
}
```

Compiler is not able to deduce the return type of g.
It shows following error-

```
temp.cpp: In function 'int main()':
temp.cpp:9:20: error: no matching function for call to 'f1(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int)'
  std::cout<< f1(f,8);
                    ^
temp.cpp:5:5: note: candidate: template<class auto:2> int f1(auto:2 (*)(int), int)
 int f1(auto (*g)(int),int a) {return g(a);}
     ^~
temp.cpp:5:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
temp.cpp:9:20: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'auto:2'
  std::cout<< f1(f,8);
                    ^
```

But no error comes in the code-

```
#include<iostream>

int f(int /* <<<<< */ a){return a;} // only (auto a) is changed to (int a)

int f1(auto (*g)(int),int a) {return g(a);}

main()
{
    std::cout<< f1(f,8);
}
```

Help me understand the error...

Comment: Note that you are relying on a gcc extension. C++14 has no such feature as `auto` for function parameters (i.e. turning those functions into template functions with a template parameter for each `auto`). Here is an equivalent version with the same error but no `auto`: https://godbolt.org/z/miMZ3r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int f(auto a){return a;}
```

is equivalent to

```
template <typename T>
int f(T a){return a;}
```

---

You cannot take the address of a template (or overload set) - that is why you're seeing that error. Workarounds:

- Take the address of the instantiation you want:

  ```
  return f1(f<int>,8);
  ```
- Make `f1` accept `auto` and pass a lambda:

  ```
  int f1(auto g, int a) {return g(a);}

  int main()
  {
      std::cout<< f1([](auto x){ f(x); },8);
  }
  ```

Comment: changing f and f1 to - 

auto f(int a){return a;}               
& 
int f1(int (*g)(auto),int a) {return g(a);}                       

and there is no error shown.
I don't see "You cannot take the address of a template" is the problem.  
If you can clarify it again..../*sorry,its not showing '\n' in comments*/

Comment: `auto f(int a){return a;}` is not a template. It's equivalent to `int f(int a){return a;}`

Comment: Ok, I was mistaken there. Thanks.